# Change my BFS so it will return all paths that are Goal and are in the same level which is minimal

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I implemented a BFS algorithm that traverses on a grid and returns a path from a certain start cell to any cell that upholds some stop condition.
The allowed moves are up, down, left, right.
I want to change it to return all the optimal (shortest paths, meaning they are on the same level in the BFS search) paths and not just the first it finds. How can I change it in an elegant way?

In my implementation, I search all cells untill I get to cell that contains 2, while I avoid cells that contain 4.
Here is my code:

```
def bfs(grid, start):
    queue = collections.deque([[start]])
    seen = set([start])
    while queue:
        path = queue.popleft()
        x, y = path[-1]
        if grid[y][x] == 2:
            return path
        for x2, y2 in ((x+1,y), (x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x,y-1)):
            if 0 <= x2 < len(grid[0]) and 0 <= y2 < len(grid) and  grid[y2][x2] != 4 and (x2, y2) not in seen:
                queue.append(path + [(x2, y2)])
                seen.add((x2, y2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment so put as an answer. I haven't tested the modification, but here's what I would do:

```
def bfs(grid, start):
    queue = collections.deque([[start]])
    seen = set([start])

    # this contains all the paths found
    found_paths = []

    # search flag recording the shortest distance
    min_path_length = None

    while queue:
        path = queue.popleft()

        # check if we already passed the min_path_length's level
        if min_path_length is not None and min_path_length < len(path):
            break

        x, y = path[-1]
        if grid[y][x] == 2:
            # check if this is the first encounter of min_path
            if min_path_length is None: min_path_length = len(path)

            # we can double check len(path) == min_path_length before adding path
            # but that wouldn't be needed if this implementation is correct
            found_paths.append(path)

        for x2, y2 in ((x+1,y), (x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x,y-1)):
            if 0 <= x2 < len(grid[0]) and 0 <= y2 < len(grid) and  grid[y2][x2] != 4 and (x2, y2) not in seen:
                queue.append(path + [(x2, y2)])
                seen.add((x2, y2))

    return found_paths
```

Comment: Checking it now, will up vote your answer shortly if it works. Thanks!